# how to merge multiple Pickle files to one in python

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have 5 Pickle files and I want to merge them to single Pickle file, I used this code

```
def combine_pickle_files(directory_path, output_file):
    result = []
    for d in os.listdir(directory_path):
        if d.endswith('.pkl'):
            with open(osp.join(path, d), 'rb') as f:
                content = pickle.load(f)
            result.append(content)
    with open('/home/dataset/result.pkl', 'wb') as out:
        pickle.dump(result, out, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

all of the Pickle files has `<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

but when I use this code I got `<class 'List'>` as result

Comment: To avoid creating a list, you should pickle each individual dataframe instead of adding them to a list and then pickling the list.

Answer (score 3):

The issue lies in the last line where you're dumping the result list to the output file. To fix this, you need to concatenate or merge the individual DataFrames into a single DataFrame before saving it to the output file.

```
import os
import os.path as osp
import pickle
import pandas as pd

def combine_pickle_files(directory_path, output_file):
    combined_df = pd.DataFrame()  # Initialize an empty DataFrame to store the merged data

    for file_name in os.listdir(directory_path):
        if file_name.endswith('.pkl'):
            file_path = osp.join(directory_path, file_name)
            with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
                content = pickle.load(f)
                if isinstance(content, pd.DataFrame):
                    combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, content], ignore_index=True)
    
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as out:
        pickle.dump(combined_df, out, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

# Example usage:
directory_path = '/home/dataset'
output_file = '/home/dataset/result.pkl'
combine_pickle_files(directory_path, output_file)
```

Comment: One piece of advice: dataframes concatenations are quite expensive operations, it's more efficient to group them in a list and do a single concatenation on it

Comment: You don't have to concatenate the data frames. It is completely acceptable to pickle multiple individual objects, such as data frames, separately.

Comment: @k0uva tnx for your code, but the output file is empty, but my files have 400k records combine